# Text in button pushed down in FF

Tags: css, forms, firefox, button, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with "Check" button on http://www.myprivacyaudit.com/. In Firefox it is pushed down and partially hidden. Does anyone of you have an idea why is that? I've spent few hours on it already, and cant find solution. Btw. I am using twitter-bootstrap

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <div id="enter-username">
      <div id="tweet_form">
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/confirm" class="form" method="post">
          <span class="at">@</span> <input class="" id="twitter_account" name="twitter_account" type="text" />
          <br/>
          <input id="twitter_account_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Check" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  input#twitter_account_submit {
    border: 5px solid black;
    background-color: #ff5255;
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
```

Comment: Can you include the code in question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this:

```
<input id="twitter_account_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Check">
```

to this:

```
<button id="twitter_account_submit" name="commit" type="submit">Check</button>
```

And in your CSS file, change this:

```
input#twitter_account_submit
```

to this:

```
#twitter_account_submit
```

Comment: Brilliant, that worked, thank you very much. How did you know that that was the reason?

Answer (score -1):

the check button is an inline element. You've declared a height of 40px on it, but you cannot control height on an inline element.

Additionally, earlier in your stylesheet you declared a line-height of 18px that is being transferred down to the button.

Remove your height declaration entirely and apply a line-height (try line-height:120%), this worked for me.

Comment: `INPUT`, `BUTTON`, and `SELECT` elements are not inline elements, although there are some distinctions between how different browsers render them that lead to that assumption. Newer browsers tend to apply `display: inline-block;` in their base CSS, which allows for modification of the height. Older browsers do tend to treat the elements as `display: inline;`, but in those browsers (I'm thinking IE6/7) using `line-height` for setting a height is not reliable.